# hypotheses testing

Tags: hypothesis-testing

so I'm new to statistics and am not very comfortable with it yet. It may be a very simple question, but I'm finding this very difficult to understand
In research papers the hypotheses are mostly in a particular direction. 
Like "satisfaction is positively related to customer retention"
If this particular hypothesis is rejected, does it mean that 'satisfaction is negatively related to customer retention' or that 'satisfaction is unrelated to customer retention'? 
Please clarify

Answer (score -2):

then satisfaction is not positively related to customer retention. that's all we know .This implies that in statistical hypothesis testing you are unable to find evidence for H0. If one rejects H0 then the only conclusion you can draw is 'We can not prove H0' or 'it is probable that H0 is false and so we accept H1 (refer power of test ) .

Comment: This is a very poor and meaningless response.